# Maui project problem with the Android binding library

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, .net-maui

I need to build a Maui app and use two java libraries from two providers. There are `.aar` files and I found the "Android java library Binding" project is not working well, therefore I use "Android Bindings Library (Xamarin)". It works with one `.arr` files from one provider. But for another project with another `.arr` file, I get this error:

> [{my Maui project name}] type=1400 audit(0.0:9379): avc: denied { write } for name="tombstoned_crash" dev="tmpfs" ino=21170 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c107,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:tombstoned_crash_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
> [libc] failed to connect to tombstoned: Permission denied

Then it crashes. Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: I don't think Xamarin Binding Libraries would work in MAUI

Comment: Yes, it works for my another .arr libraray

Comment: Did you use the non-AOSP webview in your application? The same error message can be found on the SO, you can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231326/what-is-the-meaning-of-avc-denied-read-for-name-line-in-logcat) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58008987/render-process-crashing-webview-android-pie-9).

Comment: Try the Android Java Library Binding Template.